# Reverse image archive : stacking images from bottom to top with CSS / Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, css, positioning

Wondering if anyone has a solution for this.
I would like to present an archive of thumbnail images oldest at the bottom and newest at the top. I would also like the flow itself to be reversed... something like this:

[image: reverse archive]

The page should be right aligned, with future images added to the top of the page. I am creating the page dynamically with PHP pulling image filenames from a MySQL DB. The catch here is I would love this layout to be fluid, meaning most PHP tricks for counting images and building the HTML accordingly go out the window.

Is there a way to do this with Javascript or even just CSS?

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? If the answer happens to be "only modern ones", then you can do this with just CSS.

Comment: Only modern ones would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pft6p/

This uses `float: right` to [order the `div`s as required](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pft6p/2/), then `transform: scaleY(-1)` [flips the entire container](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pft6p/1/), and lastly `transform: scaleY(-1)` again [flips each individual image back](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pft6p/).

It will work in IE9 and greater and all modern browsers.

**CSS:**

```
#container, #container > div {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
       -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
         -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
            transform: scaleY(-1);
}

#container {
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container > div {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    ..
</div>
```

Comment: I think the `transform` is a much more complicated solution then just having the PHP backend print the elements onto the page in reverse.

Comment: @George Pittarelli: Having the order reversed in the HTML and then using either of [`float: left`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pft6p/3/) or [`float: right`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pft6p/4/) doesn't quite achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Just found the following CSS code for addressing IE7 and IE8 as well `filter: flipv;`

Answer (score 2):

CSS Flexible Box Module was made for this type of thing. See a quick example I whipped up: http://jsfiddle.net/c6QLC/2/ (look at this in Firefox)

Now the bad news: you can't really rely on it yet. Not only is the spec being rewritten, the current implementation doesn't support `box-lines` (which I did include in the example), which would allow the items to be in multiple rows as opposed to being overflow.

The new spec is being written into dev versions of some browsers, so it will happen. It's just a matter of time.

**In the meantime, perhaps something like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) might fit your needs.**

Should you want to check out the spec, you can find it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

Comment: +1 as this was what I was trying (http://jsfiddle.net/aeuRm/ for a webkit example). Came across the same problem in that box-lines does not work!

Comment: Isotope is indeed very cool, thank you for introducing it to me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with jquery masonry plugin. It's a bit like isotope but free of charge for private and commercial users.