# How to reflow DIV boxes in CSS to stick to bottom right?

Tags: css, position

Let's say I have a DIV that's styled as a square, and it has squares (DIV) inside of it. I'd like the squares inside the main DIV to stack in the lower right. I can use `float: right` to to get them on the right edge, but how do I make them stack at the bottom rather than the top?

Comment: Try margin-top on the top square. That should move all of them down. I don't really know of a way for it to be done automatically, without setting an exact margin.

Comment: margin-top requires a specific # value. I don't want to do that, I'd just like a way of saying "align these on the bottom and stack them upward."

Comment: the only way I know of doing that is with tables, then in a td use attribute valign="bottom"

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7855433/405015. Am I correct to assume that your question is a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you not find a good CSS solution, jQuery can easily handle this:
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/KYt2S/1/)

```
$('.inner').each(function(i) {
    $this = $(this);
    var bottomPos = ($this.outerHeight())*i;
    $this.css('bottom', bottomPos);
});
```

HTML and CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer {
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #eee;
        position: relative;
    }
    .inner {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">One</div>
    <div class="inner">Two</div>
    <div class="inner">Three</div>
    <div class="inner">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript can be slightly improved to `$('.inner').css('bottom', function(i) { return $(this).outerHeight()*i; });`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a child to stick to the very bottom of a container, set the `position:relative` and `bottom:0px`.  However this will not stack them, you'd have to set the bottom to another value for a child to be above another child.  You could use javascript or jquery to dynamically fit them if the sizes are variable like this:

```
$('#second_element').css('bottom', $('#bottom_element').height() + 5);
```

Note: `5` is just for padding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align:bottom`

Here's a good tutorial on using "table-cell" layout:

http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "stack at the bottom", you can achieve this with the use of an inner container div that is aligned at the bottom.  Then these child squares can be float right inside of this container div, causing them to stick to the bottom of the main div, like so:

```
<div id="main_div" style="position: relative; height: 500px; width: 500px;">
   <div id="container_div" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
       <div class="right_floated_square">Square 1 Content</div>
       <div class="right_floated_square">Square 2 Content</div>
       <div class="right_floated_square">Square 3 Content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What this would do is flow these squares right to left at the bottom of the main div.  However, these child squares would still flow top to bottom inside the container div.  If you wanted them to vertically flow in reverse (bottom up), I'm not sure if that would be possible without some complex layout javascript.

Obviously, the exact styling of "right_floated_square" has been removed for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure css version: http://jsfiddle.net/zkhWA/1/

Basically place your little squares in another absolutely positioned element that is grounded to the bottom right corner of the big square using:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

Then make all the little squares float right:

```
float: right;
```

Don't forget to apply position:relative to the big square.